# Prestashop price edit on checkout

Tags: prestashop, checkout, prestashop-1.7, price

I'm not a Prestashop expert but a customer asked me if there is a way to change the price of individual products during checkout (he has a private ecommerce reserved only for his resellers so all the thing would be under control). I wanted to ask someone more experienced then me if this is at least feasible, if Prestashop (1.7) allows such a change; I tried to search for good among the modules on the store but I did not find any. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific prices on prestashop which allow you to define personalized prices for the product according to certain parameters.

Nothing to do with the webservice, but the doc is not very complete and they are not explained on the webservice doc, but you can find them from your back office.

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/resources/specific_prices/